# retrieving first value from collection

Tags: java

My code is as below :

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, ABC> x : getOfferCriteria().getCommitments()
        .entrySet()) {
    ABC abc = x.getValue();
    if (abc.getYYY() == 0) {
        abc.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve only the first value and to disable it without using a for loop, as I know the first value would be zero always

Comment: can't get what you need? please explain

Comment: Explain your question properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like:

```
new ArrayList<ABC>(getOfferCriteria().getCommitments().values()).get(0)
```

Comment: It is not clear, The map is sorted one and you will get the first element for the key which value is 0. From your solution, you assumed, the first element is always the 0.

Comment: @0mile The get is on the list not on the map.

Comment: values() will return elements whether in the same order as inserted??? if it is HashMap.. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: He asked to get the first element. No questions on sorting nor any implicit insertion order. This was one approach. I don't know if he uses LinkedHashMap or not to retain insertion order. Anyway, it was just a suggestion for him to manage his map values in a list.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, `Map`s tend not to be ordered, so there isn't a first element. Assuming it is sorted or ordered:

```
map.values().iterator().next()
```

A `TreeMap` will keep the map sorted in some particular order. `LinkedHashMap` maintains a doubly-linked list between the entries to maintain some sort of access order.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **LinkedHashMap** that the insertion order is retained. So if you create your map like

```
Map<Integer,ABC> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,ABC>();
```

then you can directly do the following(Assuming you want to disable the property of element hold by the 1st key in map) -

```
getOfferCriteria().getCommitments().get(0).setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
getOfferCriteria().getCommitments() != null ? getOfferCriteria().getCommitments().get(0) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the get method on map by passing the key value as 0

```
Example
<PRE>
        if(!getOfferCriteria().getCommitments().isEmpty()){
            Map.Entry<Integer, String> entrySet = 
                       getOfferCriteria().getCommitments().entrySet().iterator().next();
            System.out.println("hello9"+entrySet .getValue());
        }
</PRE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very lengthy one :

```
List<ABC> values = new ArrayList(yourMap.values());
Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<ABC>() {

    public int compare(ABC o1, ABC o2) {
        return o1.getYYY() - o2.getYYY();
    }
});    

values.get(0).setEnabled(false);
```